# Regular Expressions in Notepad++ starting with text and ending with incremental number

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to understand this as I'm reading tutorials and apply this to what I'm doing.

I have a file with lines of text like:

```
line1blahblahblahblah
line2blahblahblahblah
...
line10blahblahblahblah
```

I want to go in and remove the `line` and the number after it (which is incremented 1-1000 for each line) and replace it with new text leaving all the text after in tact.

Can someone explain how and explain the regex expression?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: [`^line\d+`](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Eline%5Cd%2B)

Comment: I tried reading tutorial on how to search and replace using regex but not really understating thus i needed a more detailed explanation of my specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for

```
^line\d+
```

And replace with an empty string.

*Explanation*: The `^` matches the begining of the line, the `line` matches a literal character sequence, and the `\d` matches any digit character. The `+` after the `\d` makes it match one or more digits characters.

Your Notepad++ search panel should look like this:
[image]

Comment: You might want to take into consideration `^|\A` as sometimes `^` does not go well in all types of file-encoding for the beginning of the file (string) itself. For the rest of the answer +1 :)

Comment: @Allendar I've never encountered that. Can you give an example of an encoding that would cause unusual behavior?

Comment: For what I've encountered; if you open Russian or Chinese encoded files with wrong UTF-8/UTF-16 encoding the interpretation of the file in general is still OK, but if some character are mismatched (UTF may interpret 16byte Chinese into 2 UTF-8 characters) it might result in `BOF` or stuff like `NULL`. When this happens the `^` followed by `line` will fail. For some odd reason `\Aline` worked for me in that case, as it seems to ignore the `x00` values on the start. This also proves that RegEx doesn't explicitly read bytes/hex, but interprets too.

Comment: For that reason, encoding issues are mostly best solved by reading the contents in Hex/Binary. This way you can strip out known malicious characters to prevent magically failing RegEx, as many editors will never show such hidden characters. Finally; you could also add something like `^.{0,6}line\d+` to give the contents after the start of the line some breathing space. This will mostly not really cause harm and can help skip the hidden characters.